# Изчезает стрелка в слайдере после активации

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

```js
new Swiper('.swiper-abc', {
    navigation: {
        nextEl:`.swiper-button-next`,
        prevEl: `.swiper-button-prev`,
    },
});
```

```css
.serviceProvided-section{
    background:url("../img/serviceprovidedbg.png") no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-color:#683b5b;
    min-height: 480px;
    margin: 65px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:15px 0px 15px 0px;
}
.serviceProvided-section h2{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left:60px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
/* .text-block__wrapper{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right:187px;
} */
.swiper {
    width:1200px;
    height:300px;
}
.text-block{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.text-block h3{
    color:#ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.text-block p{
    font-size:11px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.text-block__block{
    width:40%;
    margin-bottom:3em;
} 
iframe{
    width:570px;
    height: 302px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="serviceProvided-section">
  <div class="swiper-container swiper-abc">
    <h2><span class="s-letter">S</span>ervice <span class="underline">Provided</span></h2>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper"> 
      <div class="swiper-slide text-block">
        <div class="text-block__block">
          <h3>App Development</h3>
          <p class="main-content-text"></p>
         </div>
         <div class="text-block__block">
          <h3>Game Development</h3>
          <p class="main-content-text"></p>
         </div>
         <div class="text-block__block">
          <h3>App Design</h3>
          <p class="main-content-text"></p>
         </div>
         <div class="text-block__block">
          <h3>Game Design</h3>
          <p class="main-content-text"></p>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="swiper-slide">
        <iframe
           class="video-slider__video" 
           src="#" 
           title="YouTube video player" 
           frameborder="0" 
           allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
           allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
       </div>
       <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
       <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

После прокрутки 1го слайла пропадают кнопки(стрелки) пробовал выносить вне блока swiper-wrapper - полностью исчезали.
P.S Думал проблема в iframe но попробовав с обычными блоками картинок ничего не изменилось. Также выносил блоки контента под дополнительную обертку.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, конечно, будут пропадать, если быть точнее, то будут пролистываться)) Вы запихнули кнопки в `swiper-wrapper` вынесите их в `swiper-container`:

```js
new Swiper('.swiper-abc', {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: `.swiper-button-next`,
    prevEl: `.swiper-button-prev`,
  },
});
```

```css
.serviceProvided-section {
  background: url("../img/serviceprovidedbg.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #683b5b;
  min-height: 480px;
  margin: 65px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
}

.serviceProvided-section h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 60px;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* .text-block__wrapper{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right:187px;
} */

.swiper {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.text-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text-block h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.text-block p {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.text-block__block {
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

iframe {
  width: 570px;
  height: 302px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="serviceProvided-section">
  <div class="swiper-container swiper-abc">
    <h2><span class="s-letter">S</span>ervice <span class="underline">Provided</span></h2>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide text-block">
        <div class="text-block__block">
          <h3>App Development</h3>
          <p class="main-content-text"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-block__block">
          <h3>Game Development</h3>
          <p class="main-content-text"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-block__block">
          <h3>App Design</h3>
          <p class="main-content-text"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-block__block">
          <h3>Game Design</h3>
          <p class="main-content-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <iframe class="video-slider__video" src="#" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Вынес в swiper-container но теперь стрелки появляются только на 2м слайде

Comment: @17thNIIICE Вы пробовали запускать мой код, который я приложил?

Comment: Пробовал. и в свой конечный код вставлял, если в iframe стоит видео стрелок не видно, если он пуст отображается моя страница(в слайдере) и в ней уже стрелки.

Comment: Странно, почему у вас так рабоает. Попробуйте в FF запустить код на самом сайте, который я здесь приложил, может дело вообще в браузере?

Comment: Да я запускал код и работает как надо. UPD Браузер Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Вынесли navigation за приделы контейнера и дали возможность для каждой отдельной навигации крутить отдельно.

```js
//Swiper
$('.swiper-object .js-sample-slider').each(function(index, value) {
  const swiperId = $(value).data('swiper-id'); // Получаем ID карусели из data-атрибута
  const swiperNav = $('.swiper-navigation[data-swiper-id="' + swiperId + '"]'); // Находим контейнер навигации по ID карусели
  const swiper = new Swiper(value, {
    slidesPerView: 6,
    spaceBetween: 16,
    lazy: true, //lazy load
    //loop: true,                         //loop
    pagination: { //pagination(dots)
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: { //navigation(arrows)
      nextEl: swiperNav.find('.swiper-button-next')[0],
      prevEl: swiperNav.find('.swiper-button-prev')[0],
    },
    breakpoints: {
      640: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 20,
      },
      768: {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 40,
      },
      1024: {
        slidesPerView: 6,
        spaceBetween: 16,
      },
    },
  });
});

// Назначение событий на кнопки навигации
$('.swiper-navigation .swiper-button-prev').on('click', function() {
  const swiperId = $(this).closest('.swiper-navigation').data('swiper-id');
  const swiper = $('.js-sample-slider[data-swiper-id="' + swiperId + '"]')[0].swiper;
  swiper.slidePrev();
});

$('.swiper-navigation .swiper-button-next').on('click', function() {
  const swiperId = $(this).closest('.swiper-navigation').data('swiper-id');
  const swiper = $('.js-sample-slider[data-swiper-id="' + swiperId + '"]')[0].swiper;
  swiper.slideNext();
});
```

```css
/*Demo*/
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper-object {
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-navigation {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-object">
  <div class="js-sample-slider swiper" data-swiper-id="1">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-navigation" data-swiper-id="1">
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="swiper-object">
  <div class="js-sample-slider swiper" data-swiper-id="2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-navigation" data-swiper-id="2">
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```